# OAuth 2.0 and its specifications

Tags: web-applications, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, access-token

I'm trying to understand the way in which OAuth protocol is working. I had a read on its specification on [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and I am confused by different concepts here!
1- what's client_ID? should it be a unique String which client sends to the authorization server each time? is that optional? how about client_secret?
2- is access token a unique String for each user or it is something like session identifier which is the random String specific for each session?

I also have questions about Implicit Grant!
1- when do we want to use this type of grant?
2- how will the client achieve the access token? I've read that the user-agent should parse the fragment using a script sent by web-hosted client resources! but I don't understand this process! what is the web-hosted client resource exactly?

as my last question!

- is it possible for a web application to use OAuth protocol but change the name of the parameters? For example, can I use OAuth_ID instead of Client_ID in my implementation of this protocol or I have to follow the exact name of existing parameters?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A client ID (client_id) is a unique ID that is generated by the authorization server and assigned to your client application. The format of the client ID is determined by each authorization server and it's an implementation matter. It may be a string or a number. A client ID needs to be sent to the endpoints (the authorization endpoint and the token endpoint) each time. 'client_id' is a must parameter.

A client secret (client_secret) is required in some cases when a client application accesses the token endpoint. Read 2.3. and 3.2.1. of RFC 6749 carefully.

An access token is a string or a number which represents the authorization information about: who (the user) has granted what permissions (scopes) to which client application. It may be a random string/number or an encrypted string. In the former case, the implementation of the authorization server has a mapping table between the random string/number and the authorization information. In the latter case, the access token is an encrypted string which contains the authorization information.

Implicit Grant is a one-step flow to get an access token. For example, a JavaScript application (web-hosted client) prefers Implicit Grant to Authorization Code Grant. In Implicit Grant, the authorization server returns "302 Found" and Location header whose value contains the redirect URI and an access token. To extract the access token, parse the value of the Location header or implement a callback function which is called by a web-browser component you are using (e.g. WebView) when the location is being changed.

You cannot use 'OAuth_ID' as a parameter name. The exact name 'client_id' must be used.